# Refresh urls.py cache in django

Tags: python, django, nginx, fastcgi

I'm using `django` on `nginx` with `FastCGI` and i have a problem with `urls.py`. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737400/does-django-cache-url-regex-patterns-somehow), django caches url.py file and i'm - just like above question's author - not able to modify my URLs definitions.

My question is - is there any way to clear url cache in django/nginx/fcgi without server restart (which not helps anyway)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not just a urls.py thing, it's normal workflow for running a wsgi or fastcgi app. The module is in memory, and it doesn't get reloaded from disk until you tell the server that it's changed.

As per [Django's FastCGI docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/#restarting-the-spawned-server):

> If you change any Python code on your site, you'll need to tell FastCGI the code has changed. But there's no need to restart Apache in this case. Rather, just reupload mysite.fcgi, or edit the file, so that the timestamp on the file will change. When Apache sees the file has been updated, it will restart your Django application for you.
>
> If you have access to a command shell on a Unix system, you can accomplish this easily by using the touch command:
>
> > touch mysite.fcgi

For development, in most cases you can use the [django development server](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port), which watches for code changes and restarts when it sees something change.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to restart the whole server, just your FastCGI app. However, I don't know why you say this doesn't help - this is the way to do it. It can't not help.